# Nancy application error being swallowed by OWIN?

Tags: .net, .net-4.5, owin, nancy

I have a Nancy app which i've recently updated to use OWIN/Katana.

For some reason, my "real" errors are now being hidden.

This is the only generic error i receive:

> A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread.
>
> Caused By: HttpException·The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x800704CD.
> :0System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32 result, Boolean throwOnDisconnect)
> :0System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ExplicitFlush()
> :0System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean finalFlush, Boolean async)
> :0Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallStreams.OutputStream.Flush()
> :0System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
> :0System.IO.StreamWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
> :0System.IO.StreamWriter.Close()
> :0Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.System.IDisposable.Dispose()
> :0Nancy.Serialization.JsonNet.JsonNetSerializer.Serialize(String contentType, TModel model, Stream outputStream)
> :0Nancy.Owin.NancyMiddleware+<>c__DisplayClasse.b__a(NancyContext context)
> :0System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

That's not the real error. For some reason my real error isn't being logged anymore after i updated to use OWIN.

My OWIN startup has nothing but `app.UseNancy()` (no other middleware).

Here's my error handler in `ApplicationStartup`:

```
pipelines.OnError.AddItemToEndOfPipeline((context, exception) => OnError(container.Resolve<ILoggingService>(), context, exception));


private static Response OnError(ILoggingService loggingService, NancyContext context, Exception exception)
{
   // log something
}
```

What am i doing wrong? Do i have to write custom middleware to handle the errors now?

*EDIT*

An update on this. When it happens, it actually crashes my site/app pool. I'm on .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this wasn't Nancy/OWIN directly.

A library i was using (BugSnag) was causing issues. Doesn't seem it supports OWIN properly. So i removed that library and the problem stopped.